# how to construct the following dictionary, using List Comprehension?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, list-comprehension

Hello I have the following dictionary:

```
vocabulary =  {'car': 1, 'read': 3, 'yellow': 2}

weight = [23,445,56]
```

I would like to associate the first dictionary with the list of weight, as follows, the weight of the Word `car` is `23` since the value of the key `car` is one, the weight of the Word `read` is `56` since is the 3 position of the list weight and finally the wight of `yellow` is 2 since `445` is at the second position of the list, thus my desired output would be:

```
vocabulary_weight = {'yellow':445,'read':56,'car':23}
```

I tried:

```
vocabulary_weight = {key: value for (vocabulary.keys(), weight[vocabulary.value()] ) 
                     in vocabulary}
```

but I am getting:

```
  File "<ipython-input-7-471237aaf624>", line 7
    vocabulary_weight = {key: value for (vocabulary.keys(), weight[vocabulary.value()] ) in vocabulary}
                                       ^
SyntaxError: can't assign to function call
```

So I would like to receive support to achive the desired output, thanks for the support,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can iterate over `vocabulary.items()` This gives you the keys and the values as tuple. Unpack to with `key, value` and use `value - 1` as the index of your list:

```
>>> vocabulary =  {'car': 1, 'read': 3, 'yellow': 2}
>>> weight = [23,445,56]
>>> vocabulary_weight = {key: weight[value - 1] for key, value in vocabulary.items()}
>>> vocabulary_weight
{'car': 23, 'read': 56, 'yellow': 445}
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
vocabulary =  {'car': 1, 'read': 3, 'yellow': 2}
weight = [23,445,56]

vocabulary_weight = {key : weight[int(vocabulary[key]) - 1] for key in vocabulary.keys()}
```